# I'm trying to integrate generate and verify OTP for user signup node.js backend with my flutter application with Twilio 2FA OTP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, twilio

User was not valid
{
email: 'is invalid',
cellphone: 'is invalid',
message: 'User was not valid',
success: false,
errors: {
email: 'is invalid',
cellphone: 'is invalid',
message: 'User was not valid'
},
error_code: '60027'
}

So this is the error I got every time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.